# Update embedded document meteor / mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, nosql

I am building an app using Meteor and I am trying to update an embedded document. The following code works in the terminal console:

```
db.users.update(
{_id: '9pqovAcygbSGX6ThR', 'mailingAddresses.addressId': '12345'},
{$set: {"mailingAddresses.$.streetAddress" : 'asdfasfsdaf',
    "mailingAddresses.$.city": 'Montreal'
    }}
)
```

However, when I translate that code into my methods.js file, the document does not update accordingly:

```
Meteor.users.update(
        {_id: this.userId, 'mailingAddresses.addressId': 'addressDetails.addressId'},
        {$set: {'mailingAddresses.$.streetAddress' : 'addressDetails.streetAddress',
                'mailingAddresses.$.city': 'addressDetails.city'
                }}

            )
}

});
```

Note - addressDetails is an object that contains the updated address details. My console correctly prints out information contained in addressDetails.

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You recognise `'addressDetails.addressId'` is a string, right? Try updating without the string quotes: `{_id: this.userId, 'mailingAddresses.addressId': addressDetails.addressId},
        {$set: {'mailingAddresses.$.streetAddress' : addressDetails.streetAddress,
                'mailingAddresses.$.city': addressDetails.city
                }}
`

Comment: thanks - i tried that already.. didn't work either :/

Comment: you get something in the console? some warning/error? also print all the strings inside `console.log(this.userId) console.log(addressDetails.addressId) console.log(addressDetails.streetAddress) console.log(addressDetails.city)` on the meteor console you are working with static values but on the method you use objects values and some `this` context, someone of that values should return `undefined`

Comment: i solved it.. i wasn't passing in the addressId value properly lol